# \emph isn´t working with scrartcl

Tags: koma-script, emphasis

I want to use `\emph{}`, but as I changed all `\textit{}` in `\emph{}`, my code isn´t working anymore. I am using TeX-Studio and suddenly it´s not showing me the page anymore. It says "Underfull hbox in..." and is complaining about my `bibtotoc` and `fancyhdr`, which both worked bevor. Is the `\emph{}` only possible in the `article`-class? I am using the `scrartcl`-class and the following packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, bibtotocnumbered]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{color}  
\usepackage{colortbl}  
\usepackage{epsfig} 
\usepackage{epsf}            
\usepackage{float}           
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=1.9cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{empheq}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
    \textit{This quote is making problems now.} \newline
\end{quote}

And i \emph{can´t} use this, but why? Also my references aren´t working anymore. But when I change the \emph back in \textit everything is fine. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\emph` should also work with `\documentclass{scrartlc}`. If I add `\documentclass{scrartlc}` to the very top of your code example and compile the document I get italics with `\emph` as expected. Can you please complete your code example to make sure it is compilable and compile the example to double check if it reproduces the issue.

Comment: Ah, sorry, of course on the very top there is
 ``` \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, bibtotocnumbered]{scrartcl}

Comment: In any case you may want to clean up your preamble a bit. You are loading a lot of packages. Do you need all of them? Do you even know what every package does? (You won't need `graphics` if you load `graphicx`. You shouldn't be using `fancyhdr` with a KOMA Script class like `scrartcl`. It is usually not useful to use `cite` and `natbib` together. Do you need `epsfig` and `epsf`? Usually `hyperref` should be loaded last [except for a few documented exceptions].)

Comment: Yeah, maybe I use a lot of packages, you are right.. and now my example is working. But on my bachelor thesis not and thats why I am wondering.

Comment: You can edit your question to include the missing line in the code example. Please compile the complete code example you posted in a new, empt folder and check if it reproduces the undesirable behaviour. If the example does not reproduce the problematic behaviour, you can add as much code from your Bachelor's thesis as necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: When I run your code (while adding the instruction `\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, bibtotocnumbered]{scrartcl}`...), I also find that the instruction `\emph{can't}` works just fine, i.e., its argument is rendered in italics. FWIW, I employ MacTeX2020 (with all updates applied thru this morning) on a system that run MacOS 10.15.4.

Comment: After I cleaned my preamble it worked! Thanks @moewe !

Comment: no documents should be loading epsf or epsfig packages (they were legacy packages when latex2e came out in 1993 to offer some compatibility with documents written in the 1980s so unless you have been working on your thesis for a _long_ time it's surprising to see them...